# Laravel script messaging is not opening (Laravel, livewire)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

i found laravel script, it's a platform script for freelancers. When I go to the Messages section, the screen does not turn on.
Normally the link should be like this: [www.example.com/message/[conversation-id]](http://www.example.com/message/%5Bconversation-id%5D) but the link opens; [www.example.com/message/](http://www.example.com/message/).
So I can't use the messaging page. I will share a few codes that I consider necessary. Please let me know if it's missing.

routes/web.php

```
// Messages
    Route::namespace('Messages')->prefix('messages')->middleware('auth')->group(function() {

        // Index
        Route::get('/', MessagesComponent::class);

        // New
        Route::get('new/{username}', NewComponent::class);

        // Conversation
        Route::get('/{conversationId}', ConversationComponent::class);

    });
```

app/Http/Livewire/Main/Messages/ConversationComponent.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Main\Messages;

use App\Http\Validators\Main\Messages\SendValidator;
use App\Models\Conversation;
use App\Models\ConversationMessage;
use App\Notifications\User\Everyone\NewMessage;
use Cache;
use Livewire\Component;
use Artesaos\SEOTools\Traits\SEOTools as SEOToolsTrait;

class ConversationComponent extends Component
{
    use SEOToolsTrait;
    
    public $conversation;
    public $message;

    /**
     * Init component
     *
     * @param string $conversationId
     * @return void
     */
    public function mount($conversationId)
    {
        // Get conversation
        $conversation = Conversation::where('uid', $conversationId)->first();

        // Check if conversation eists
        if (!$conversation) {
            return redirect('messages');
        }

        // Check if user has permissions to see this conversation
        if ($conversation->from_id === auth()->id() || $conversation->to_id === auth()->id()) {
            
            // Set conversation
            $this->conversation = $conversation;

        } else {

            // User has no permission
            return redirect('messages');

        }

        // Mark messages as read
        $this->markAsRead();

    }


    /**
     * Render component
     *
     * @return Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function render()
    {
        // SEO
        $separator   = settings('general')->separator;
        $title       = __('messages.t_messages') . " $separator " . settings('general')->title;
        $description = settings('seo')->description;
        $ogimage     = src( settings('seo')->ogimage );

        $this->seo()->setTitle( $title );
        $this->seo()->setDescription( $description );
        $this->seo()->setCanonical( url()->current() );
        $this->seo()->opengraph()->setTitle( $title );
        $this->seo()->opengraph()->setDescription( $description );
        $this->seo()->opengraph()->setUrl( url()->current() );
        $this->seo()->opengraph()->setType('website');
        $this->seo()->opengraph()->addImage( $ogimage );
        $this->seo()->twitter()->setImage( $ogimage );
        $this->seo()->twitter()->setUrl( url()->current() );
        $this->seo()->twitter()->setSite( "@" . settings('seo')->twitter_username );
        $this->seo()->twitter()->addValue('card', 'summary_large_image');
        $this->seo()->metatags()->addMeta('fb:page_id', settings('seo')->facebook_page_id, 'property');
        $this->seo()->metatags()->addMeta('fb:app_id', settings('seo')->facebook_app_id, 'property');
        $this->seo()->metatags()->addMeta('robots', 'index, follow, max-image-preview:large, max-snippet:-1, max-video-preview:-1', 'name');
        $this->seo()->jsonLd()->setTitle( $title );
        $this->seo()->jsonLd()->setDescription( $description );
        $this->seo()->jsonLd()->setUrl( url()->current() );
        $this->seo()->jsonLd()->setType('WebSite');

        return view('livewire.main.messages.conversation', [
            'messages'      => $this->messages,
            'conversations' => $this->conversations
        ])->extends('livewire.main.layout.app')->section('content');
    }


    /**
     * Get messages
     *
     * @return object
     */
    public function getMessagesProperty()
    {
        return ConversationMessage::where('conversation_id', $this->conversation->id)->latest()->paginate(100);
    }


    /**
     * Get latest conversations
     *
     * @return object
     */
    public function getConversationsProperty()
    {
        return Conversation::where('from_id', auth()->id())
                            ->orWhere('to_id', auth()->id())
                            ->latest('last_message_at')
                            ->get();
    }


    /**
     * Send a message
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function send()
    {
        try {

            // Validate form
            SendValidator::validate($this);

            // Get conversation
            $conversation = Conversation::where('uid', $this->conversation->uid)
                                        ->where(function($query) {
                                            return $query->where('from_id', auth()->id())->orWhere('to_id', auth()->id());
                                        })
                                        ->first();

            // Check if conversation exists
            if (!$conversation) {
                
                // Conversation not exists
                $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('alert',[
                    "message" => __('messages.t_conversation_not_exists'),
                    "type"    => "error"
                ]);

                return;

            }

            // Check if conversation blocked
            if ($conversation->status === 'blocked') {
                
                // Conversation not exists
                $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('alert',[
                    "message" => __('messages.t_u_cant_reply_this_conversation'),
                    "type"    => "error"
                ]);

                return;

            }

            // Save message
            $message                       = new ConversationMessage();
            $message->uid                  = uid();
            $message->conversation_id      = $this->conversation->id;
            $message->message_from         = auth()->id();
            $message->message_to           = $conversation->from_id === auth()->id() ? $conversation->to_id : $conversation->from_id;
            $message->message              = clean($this->message);
            $message->save();

            // Update last message
            $conversation->last_message_at = now();
            $conversation->save();

            // Refresh conversation
            $this->conversation            = $conversation;

            // Check if user who will receive this message is offline
            if (!$conversation->sender->isOnline()) {

                // Set cache key
                $cache_key = "messages-notification-email-conversation-" . $conversation->uid;
                
                // User right now is offline
                // We have to get last message
                // Because we can't send notification on every new message
                // So we will make sure that at least 1 hour past since last message
                if (!Cache::has($cache_key)) {
                    
                    // Send a notification to him via email
                    $conversation->sender->notify( (new NewMessage($conversation, $message))->locale(config('app.locale')) );

                    // Send notification
                    notification([
                        'text'    => 't_u_have_new_message_from_username',
                        'action'  => url('messages', $conversation->uid),
                        'user_id' => $conversation->sender->id,
                        'params'  => ['username' => auth()->user()->username]
                    ]);

                    // Set cache key, to prevent multiple notification at short time
                    Cache::set($cache_key, true, now()->addHour());
                    
                }
                

            }

            // Reset form
            $this->reset('message');

        } catch (\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException $e) {

            // Validation error
            $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('alert',[
                "message" => __('messages.t_toast_form_validation_error'),
                "type"    => "error"
            ]);

            throw $e;

        } catch (\Throwable $th) {

            // Error
            $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('alert',[
                "message" => __('messages.t_toast_something_went_wrong'),
                "type"    => "error"
            ]);

            throw $th;

        }
    }


    /**
     * Block this conversation
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function block()
    {
        // Get conversation
        // We have to load conversation to prevent user from block another one
        $conversation             = Conversation::where('uid', $this->conversation->uid)->where(function($query) {
                                                    return $query->where('from_id', auth()->id())->orWhere('to_id', auth()->id());
                                                })->where('status', 'active')->firstOrFail();
        
        // Block conversation
        $conversation->status     = 'blocked';
        $conversation->blocked_by = auth()->id();
        $conversation->save();

        // Update conversation
        $this->conversation = $conversation;

        // Success
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('alert',[
            "message" => __('messages.t_conversation_blocked_successfully')
        ]);
    }

    
    /**
     * Mark message as read
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function markAsRead()
    {
        // Mark all messages as read
        ConversationMessage::where('conversation_id', $this->conversation->id)
                            ->where('message_from', '!=', auth()->id())
                            ->update([
                                'is_seen' => true
                            ]);
    }
    
}
```

app/Http/Livewire/Main/Messages/MessagesComponent.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Main\Messages;

use App\Models\Conversation;
use Livewire\Component;
use Artesaos\SEOTools\Traits\SEOTools as SEOToolsTrait;

class MessagesComponent extends Component
{
    use SEOToolsTrait;

    /**
     * Render component
     *
     * @return Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function render()
    {
        // SEO
        $separator   = settings('general')->separator;
        $title       = __('messages.t_messages') . " $separator " . settings('general')->title;
        $description = settings('seo')->description;
        $ogimage     = src( settings('seo')->ogimage );

        $this->seo()->setTitle( $title );
        $this->seo()->setDescription( $description );
        $this->seo()->setCanonical( url()->current() );
        $this->seo()->opengraph()->setTitle( $title );
        $this->seo()->opengraph()->setDescription( $description );
        $this->seo()->opengraph()->setUrl( url()->current() );
        $this->seo()->opengraph()->setType('website');
        $this->seo()->opengraph()->addImage( $ogimage );
        $this->seo()->twitter()->setImage( $ogimage );
        $this->seo()->twitter()->setUrl( url()->current() );
        $this->seo()->twitter()->setSite( "@" . settings('seo')->twitter_username );
        $this->seo()->twitter()->addValue('card', 'summary_large_image');
        $this->seo()->metatags()->addMeta('fb:page_id', settings('seo')->facebook_page_id, 'property');
        $this->seo()->metatags()->addMeta('fb:app_id', settings('seo')->facebook_app_id, 'property');
        $this->seo()->metatags()->addMeta('robots', 'index, follow, max-image-preview:large, max-snippet:-1, max-video-preview:-1', 'name');
        $this->seo()->jsonLd()->setTitle( $title );
        $this->seo()->jsonLd()->setDescription( $description );
        $this->seo()->jsonLd()->setUrl( url()->current() );
        $this->seo()->jsonLd()->setType('WebSite');

        return view('livewire.main.messages.messages', [
            'conversations' => $this->conversations 
        ])->extends('livewire.main.layout.app')->section('content');
    }


    /**
     * Get latest conversations
     *
     * @return object
     */
    public function getConversationsProperty()
    {
        return Conversation::where(function($query) {
                                return $query->where('from_id', auth()->id())->orWhere('to_id', auth()->id());
                            })
                            ->latest('last_message_at')
                            ->get();
    }
    
}
```

Create new conversation;
app/Http/Livewire/Main/Messages/NewComponent.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Main\Messages;

use App\Models\Conversation;
use App\Models\User;
use Livewire\Component;
use Artesaos\SEOTools\Traits\SEOTools as SEOToolsTrait;

class NewComponent extends Component
{
    use SEOToolsTrait;
    
    /**
     * Init component
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return void
     */
    public function mount($username)
    {
        // Get user
        $user = User::where('username', $username)
                    ->whereIn('status', ['active', 'verified'])
                    ->where('id', '!=', auth()->id())
                    ->first();

        // Check if user exists
        if (!$user) {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        // Check if there a conversation between these users before
        $conversation = Conversation::where(function($builder) use($user) {
                                        return $builder->where(function($query) use($user) {
                                            return $query->where('from_id', auth()->id())->orWhere('from_id', $user->id);
                                        })->where(function($query) use($user) {
                                            return $query->where('to_id', auth()->id())->orWhere('to_id', $user->id);
                                        });
                                    })->first();

        // Check if exists
        if (!$conversation) {
            
            // Create new conversation
            $conversation = Conversation::create([
                'uid'     => uid(),
                'from_id' => auth()->id(),
                'to_id'   => $user->id
            ]);

        }

        // Set redirect url
        $url = "messages/$conversation->uid";

        // Redirect to conversation
        return redirect($url);

    }
    
}
```

link when I open a new chat or click on an existing chat; It comes as [www.example.com/message](http://www.example.com/message). I will be glad if you can solve it.

Comment: If the `conversationId` records doesn't find on the conversation table then you redirect it to the `/messages` url pages. That's why you were redirected to www.example.com/messages link. You can also flash the `Conversation not found` message with redirection, so that you know what's going on.

Comment: how can add flash message

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to put message in the session.

```
if (!$conversation) {
    return redirect('messages')->with('error_message', 'Conversation not found!');
}

if (!$permission) {
    return redirect('messages')->with('error_message', 'User has no permission!');
}

if (!$user) {
    return redirect('/')->with('error_message', 'User not found!');
}
```

Then, In the layout file you have to get message from session.

```
@if (session('error_message'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{ session('error_message' }}</div>
@endif
```

Comment: what files do i write them in sir?

Comment: i added in ConversationComponent.php  and say <ErrorException - Undefined variable $conversation>